# Dropdown navigation menu won't show post on filtered category

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu

I am using  "laravel/framework": "^10.10" and I have defined posts and categories on my project. I am trying to implement a dropdown navigation function to display the post on each corresponding category but when I try doing it like this `@foreach($posts->items() as $post)` it will display every the posts in all the categories instead of being filtered by category but  when I try to filter it by category like this `@foreach($category->posts as $post)` it will not show anything when clicked on it. Here's my code

```
    <nav class="w-full py-4 border-t border-b bg-gray-100" x-data="{ open: false }">

    <div class="block sm:hidden">
        <a href="#" class="block md:hidden text-base font-bold uppercase text-center flex justify-center items-center" @click="open = !open">
            Topics <i :class="open ? 'fa-chevron-down': 'fa-chevron-up'" class="fas ml-2"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div :class="open ? 'block': 'hidden'" class="w-full flex-grow sm:flex sm:items-center sm:w-auto">
        <div class="w-full container mx-auto flex flex-col sm:flex-row items-center justify-center text-sm font-bold uppercase mt-0 px-6 py-2">
            <a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="hover:bg-gray-400 rounded py-2 px-4 mx-2">Home</a>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <div class="relative inline-block text-left" x-data="{ openDropdown: false }">
                    <button @click="openDropdown = !openDropdown" type="button" class="hover:bg-gray-400 rounded py-2 px-4 mx-2">
                        {{ $category->title }}  <i :class="openDropdown ? 'fa-chevron-up': 'fa-chevron-down'" class="fas ml-2"></i>
                    </button>

                    <div x-show="openDropdown" @click.away="openDropdown = false" class="absolute right-0 w-40 mt-2 origin-top-right bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-lg">

                        <!-- Dropdown content -->
                        @foreach($category->posts as $post)
                            <a href="{{ route('view', $post->slug) }}" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100">{{ $post->title }}</a>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
            <a href="#" class="hover:bg-gray-400 rounded py-2 px-4 mx-2">About us</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

already check controller and models and seems to me that categories and posts are properly related I do not understand why it will not display the post on each corresponding category here some examples of my models and controls:

**Category.php**

```
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug'];

    public function posts(): belongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(  Post::class);
    }
}
```

**Post.php**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'thumbnail', 'body', 'active', 'published_at', 'user_id'];
    protected $casts = [
        'published_at' => 'datetime'
    ];
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( related: User::class);
    }


    public function categories(): belongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(  Category::class);


    }
```

**PostController.php**

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    
    public function index(): View 
    {

        $posts = Post::query()
            ->where('active', '=', 1)
            ->whereDate('published_at', '<', Carbon::now())
            ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);
    
        $categories = Category::query()
            ->leftJoin('category_post', 'categories.id', '=', 'category_post.category_id')
            ->select('categories.title', 'categories.slug', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('categories.id', 'categories.title', 'categories.slug') // Include 'categories.title' in GROUP BY
            ->orderByDesc('total')
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();

            // dd($categories, $categories->toArray(), $posts, $posts->toArray());
    
        return view('home', compact('posts', 'categories'));
    }

  
 

   
    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        if(!$post->active || $post->published_at > Carbon::now()){
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        $next = Post::query()
        ->where('active', true)
        ->whereDate('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
        ->whereDate('published_at', '<', $post->published_at)
        ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
        ->limit(1)
        ->first();

        $prev = Post::query()
        ->where('active', true)
        ->whereDate('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
        ->whereDate('published_at', '<', $post->published_at)
        ->orderBy('published_at', 'asc')
        ->limit(1)
        ->first();


        return view('post.view', compact('post', 'prev', 'next'));
    }

    public function byCategory(Category $category)
    {

        $posts = Post::query()
        ->join('category_post', 'posts.id', '=', 'category_post.post_id')
        ->where('category_post.category_id', '=', $category->id)
        ->where('active', '=', true)
        ->whereDate('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
        ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);

    return view('home', compact('posts'));
 
}
}
```

Comment: How about this $category->posts()->get() as $post in loop?